# Is the size of C "int" 2 bytes or 4 bytes?

Tags: c, int, byte

Does an Integer variable in C occupy 2 bytes or 4 bytes? What are the factors that it depends on?

Most of the textbooks say integer variables occupy 2 bytes.
But when I run a program printing the successive addresses of an array of integers it shows the difference of 4.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_variable_types_and_declarations#Basic_types

Comment: `int` is just one of several *integer* types. You asked about the size of "integer"; you probably meant to ask about the size of `int`.

Comment: And you should find better textbooks. A textbook that says an `int` is 2 bytes (a) probably refers to an old system, and (b) fails to make it clear that the size will vary from one system to another. The best book on C is "The C Programming Language" by Kernighan and Ritchie, though it assumes some programming experience. See also question 18.10 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/).

Comment: Try `#define int int64_t` on a 64-bit platform, so neither. Just use `sizeof`. ;-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the C++ standard state the size of int, long type to be?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589575/what-does-the-c-standard-state-the-size-of-int-long-type-to-be)

Answer (score 231):

I know it's equal to `sizeof(int)`. The size of an `int` is really compiler dependent. Back in the day, when processors were 16 bit, an `int` was 2 bytes. Nowadays, it's most often 4 bytes on a 32-bit as well as 64-bit systems.

Still, using `sizeof(int)` is the best way to get the size of an integer for the specific system the program is executed on.

**EDIT:** Fixed wrong statement that `int` is 8 bytes on most 64-bit systems. For example, it is 4 bytes on 64-bit GCC.

Comment: @RajivPrathap: Well, it's compiler-dependent, but the compiler decides whether or not it's also machine-dependent. :)

Comment: If you need the size for the preproccesor, you can check the predefined macros such as INT_MAX. If the value is not the one expected by your code, then the byte size of int is different on the current compiler/platform combination.

Comment: Not just machine dependent, it also depends on the operating system running on the machine. For instance long in Win64 is 4 bytes whereas long in Linux64 is 8 bytes.

Comment: wrong. on most 64-bit systems int is still 4 bytes https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models

Comment: My system is 64 bit and size of int is 4B . Why it is so ?

Comment: @AkhilNadhPC There are papers about this. I'll bet people think 32 bits are enough, and using 32 instead of 64 allows for optimizations such as SSE.

Comment: `sizeof(int)` can be any value from `1`. A byte is not required to be 8 bits and some machines don't have a 8 bit addressable unit (which basically is the definition of a _byte_ in the standard). The answer is not correct without further information.

Comment: I second @toohonestforthissite. Using `sizeof(int)` is not advised because alone it doesn't actually convey useful information; the problem is that `sizeof` determines how many *bytes* in its operand, but doesn't tell you how many *bits* are in a byte. You need to multiply by `CHAR_BIT` for that. There may also be [padding bits](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.6.2) which means your "32-bit integer" might only be able to store 16-bit values anyway. I think what you meant to write is "using `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX` is the best way to get the information you desire, *not* `sizeof`"...

Comment: I've been working on embedded systems for over 10 years. I've never come a cross a nibble addressable unit, or a byte/nibble system. Yes, you can have stuff shifted across nibbles etc, and only take up to 28 bits etc, but you're still secretly storing 32 bytes, and therefore, sizeof(int)==4 is more useful for dynamic memory allocation (ie malloc). It really depends on what question you're trying to answer.

Comment: @yhyrcanus I worked with [TMS34010](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TMS34010#:~:text=The%20TMS34010%20is%20a%20bit,sharing%20a%20sixteenth%20stack%20pointer.&text=The%20TMS34010%20is%20capable%20of,an%20ANSI%20compliant%20C%20compiler.).  It is bit  addressable.

Answer (score 121):

This is one of the points in C that can be confusing at first, but the C standard only specifies a *minimum range* for integer types that is guaranteed to be supported. `int` is guaranteed to be able to hold -32767 to 32767, which requires 16 bits. In that case, `int`, is 2 bytes. However, implementations are free to go beyond that minimum, as you will see that many modern compilers make `int` 32-bit (which also means 4 bytes pretty ubiquitously).

The reason your book says 2 bytes is most probably because it's old.  At one time, this was the norm. In general, you should always use the `sizeof` operator if you need to find out how many bytes it is on the platform you're using.

To address this, C99 added new types where you can explicitly ask for a certain sized integer, for example `int16_t` or `int32_t`.  Prior to that, there was no universal way to get an integer of a specific width (although most platforms provided similar types on a per-platform basis).

Comment: @nevanking: On a two's complement machine (which is every machine I know of...), yes. But, C doesn't guarantee it to be the case.

Comment: @nevanking I'm completely new to C, but isn't it 32767 because otherwise it would be using another bit|byte? Imagine, I can hold 3 digits (0 or 1), so I can go from 000 to 111 (which is decimal 7). 7 is right before an exponent of 2. If I could go until 8 (1000) then I could use those 4 digits all the way up to 15! Such as 32767 is right before an exponent of 2, exhausting all the bits|bytes it has available.

Comment: @RSerrao I'm not a C expert either but AFAIK for positive numbers it's one less than the maximum negative number. So -8 to 7, -256 to 255 and so on. Negative numbers don't have to count the zero.

Comment: @nevanking You are right! O.o I forgot about the negative numbers and when I wrote my comment, somewhere in the middle, I forgot you pointed out the negative number :D You are certainly sure! Most of all, it even makes sense!

Comment: "16 bits. In that case, int, is 2 bytes" can be wrong, if CHAR_BIT is 16, sizeof(int) can be 1 byte (or char).

Comment: @nevanking: only if you assume 2's complement representation for signed `int`.  C doesn't make that assumption.  1's complement and sign-magnitude systems can't represent `-32768` in 16 bits; rather, they have two representations for zero (positive and negative).  That's why the minimum range for an `int` is `[-32767..32767]`.

Comment: It's also worth noting that there are implementations where -0 is used in twos complement representation, since accessing the negative zero is technically UB you get an extra value, that value is `-INT_MIN + 1` for `int`, for example... so you get the extra value on the positive end of the spectrum... well, the manual says *"CONFORMANCE/TWOSARITH causes negative zero, (2<sup>36</sup>)-1, to be considered a large unsigned integer by the generated code"*, though I really think they mean ones complement or sign and magnitude,else their implementation can't be compliant. Compiler devs nowadays? :/

Answer (score 37):

There's no specific answer. It depends on the platform. It is implementation-defined. It can be 2, 4 or something else.

The idea behind `int` was that it was supposed to match the natural "word" size on the given platform: 16 bit on 16-bit platforms, 32 bit on 32-bit platforms, 64 bit on 64-bit platforms, you get the idea. However, for backward compatibility purposes some compilers prefer to stick to 32-bit `int` even on 64-bit platforms.

The time of 2-byte `int` is long gone though (16-bit platforms?) unless you are using some embedded platform with 16-bit word size. Your textbooks are probably very old.

Comment: `The idea behind int was that it was supposed to match the natural "word" size on the given platform` - This is what I was looking for. Any idea what the reason may be ? In a free world, int could occupy any number of consecutive bytes in the memory right ? 8, 16 whatever

Answer (score 23):

The answer to this question depends on which platform you are using.
But irrespective of platform, you can reliably assume the following types:

```
 [8-bit] signed char: -127 to 127
 [8-bit] unsigned char: 0 to 255
 [16-bit]signed short: -32767 to 32767
 [16-bit]unsigned short: 0 to 65535
 [32-bit]signed long: -2147483647 to 2147483647
 [32-bit]unsigned long: 0 to 4294967295
 [64-bit]signed long long: -9223372036854775807 to 9223372036854775807
 [64-bit]unsigned long long: 0 to 18446744073709551615
```

Comment: Someone edited your post to "fix" the ranges, but I'm not sure if your edit adequately reflects your intent. It assumes a two's complement implementation, which will be true in *most* cases, but not all. Since your answer specifically points out the implementation-dependence, I'm thinking the edit is probably wrong. If you agree, please be sure to revert the edit.

Comment: @k06a **your edit was incorrect**. You've specifically changed the original ranges into 2-complement ranges - these are **not** the ones specified in the C standard.

Comment: @CodyGray this has been fluctuating back and forth, having been 1's complement compliant for last 3 years and OP not saying anything so I reverted an edit that changed it to 2's complement with "fix ranges", since it says "you can reliably assume", which is still not exactly true.

Comment: i think there's a slight inaccuracy, should be -128 to 127, -32768 to 32767, -2147483648 to 2147483657 and -9223372036854775808 to -9223372036854775807

Answer (score 18):

**C99 N1256 standard draft**

http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf

The size of `int` and all other integer types are implementation defined, C99 only specifies:

- minimum size guarantees
- relative sizes between the types

5.2.4.2.1 "Sizes of integer types `<limits.h>`" gives the minimum sizes:

> 1 [...] Their implementation-defined values shall be equal or greater in magnitude (absolute value) to those shown [...]
>
> - UCHAR_MAX 255 // 2 8 − 1
> - USHRT_MAX 65535 // 2 16 − 1
> - UINT_MAX 65535 // 2 16 − 1
> - ULONG_MAX 4294967295 // 2 32 − 1
> - ULLONG_MAX 18446744073709551615 // 2 64 − 1

6.2.5 "Types" then says:

> 8 For any two integer types with the same signedness and different integer conversion rank
> (see 6.3.1.1), the range of values of the type with smaller integer conversion rank is a
> subrange of the values of the other type.

and 6.3.1.1 "Boolean, characters, and integers" determines the relative conversion ranks:

> 1 Every integer type has an integer conversion rank defined as follows:
>
> - The rank of long long int shall be greater than the rank of long int, which
>   shall be greater than the rank of int, which shall be greater than the rank of short
>   int, which shall be greater than the rank of signed char.
> - The rank of any unsigned integer type shall equal the rank of the corresponding
>   signed integer type, if any.
> - For all integer types T1, T2, and T3, if T1 has greater rank than T2 and T2 has
>   greater rank than T3, then T1 has greater rank than T3

Answer (score 16):

> Does an Integer variable in C occupy 2 bytes or 4 bytes?

That depends on the platform you're using, as well as how your compiler is configured. The only authoritative answer is to use the [`sizeof`](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.3.4) operator to see how big an integer is in your specific situation.

---

> What are the factors that it depends on?

*Range* might be best considered, rather than *size*. Both will vary in practice, though it's much more fool-proof to choose variable types by range than size as we shall see. It's also important to note that the standard encourages us to consider choosing our integer types based on *range* rather than *size*, but for now let's *ignore the standard practice*, and let our curiosity explore `sizeof`, bytes and `CHAR_BIT`, and integer representation... let's burrow down the rabbit hole and see it for ourselves...

---

**`sizeof`, bytes and `CHAR_BIT`**

The following statement, taken from the C standard (linked to above), describes this in words that I don't think can be improved upon.

> The `sizeof` operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which may be an expression or the parenthesized name of a type. The size is determined from the type of the operand.

Assuming a clear understanding will lead us to a discussion about *bytes*. It's commonly assumed that a *byte* is eight bits, when in fact [`CHAR_BIT` tells you how many bits are in a byte](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note49). That's just another one of those nuances which isn't considered when talking about *the common two (or four) byte integers*.

Let's wrap things up so far:

- `sizeof` => size in bytes, and
- `CHAR_BIT` => number of bits in byte

Thus, Depending on your system, `sizeof (unsigned int)` could be *any* value greater than zero (not just 2 or 4), as if `CHAR_BIT` is 16, then *a single (sixteen-bit) byte* has enough bits in it to represent the sixteen bit integer described by the standards (quoted below). That's not necessarily useful information, is it? Let's delve deeper...

---

**Integer representation**

The C standard specifies the minimum precision/range for all standard integer types (and `CHAR_BIT`, too, fwiw) [here](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.2.4.2.1). From this, we can derive *a minimum* for how many bits are required to store *the value*, but we may as well just choose our variables based on *ranges*. Nonetheless, a huge part of the detail required for this answer resides here. For example, the following that the standard `unsigned int` requires (at least) sixteen bits of storage:

> ```
> UINT_MAX                                65535 // 2¹⁶ - 1
> ```

**Thus we can see that `unsigned int` require (*at least*) 16 bits**, which is where you get the *two bytes* (assuming `CHAR_BIT` is 8)... and later when that limit increased to `2³² - 1`, people were stating 4 bytes instead. This explains the phenomena you've observed:

> Most of the textbooks say integer variables occupy 2 bytes. But when I run a program printing the successive addresses of an array of integers it shows the difference of 4.

You're using an ancient textbook and compiler which is teaching you non-portable C; the author who wrote your textbook might not even be aware of `CHAR_BIT`. You *should* upgrade your textbook (and compiler), and strive to remember that I.T. is an ever-evolving field that you need to stay *ahead of* to compete... Enough about that, though; let's see what other non-portable secrets those *underlying integer bytes* store...

**Value bits** are what the common misconceptions appear to be counting. The above example uses an `unsigned` integer type which typically contains only value bits, so it's easy to miss the devil in the detail.

**Sign bits**... In the above example I quoted `UINT_MAX` as being the upper limit for `unsigned int` because it's a trivial example to extract the value `16` from the comment. For signed types, in order to distinguish between positive and negative values (that's the sign), we need to also include the sign bit.

> ```
> INT_MIN                                -32768 // -(2¹⁵)
> INT_MAX                                +32767 // 2¹⁵ - 1
> ```

**Padding bits**... While it's not common to encounter computers that have padding bits in integers, the C standard allows that to happen; some machines (i.e. [this one](https://public.support.unisys.com/2200/docs/cp13.2/pdf/78310430-015.pdf)) implement larger integer types by combining two smaller (signed) integer values together... and when you combine signed integers, you get a wasted sign bit. That wasted bit is considered *padding* in C. Other examples of padding bits might include [parity bits and trap bits](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note53).

---

As you can see, the standard seems to encourage considering ranges like `INT_MIN`..`INT_MAX` and [other minimum/maximum values from the standard](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.2.4.2.1) when choosing integer types, and *discourages* relying upon sizes as there are other subtle factors likely to be forgotten such as `CHAR_BIT` and padding bits which might affect the value of `sizeof (int)` (i.e. the common misconceptions of *two-byte and four-byte integers* neglects these details).

Answer (score 9):

> Is the size of C “int” 2 bytes or 4 bytes?

The answer is "yes" / "no" / "maybe" / "maybe not".

The C programming language specifies the following: the smallest addressable unit, known by `char` and also called *"byte"*, is exactly `CHAR_BIT` bits wide, where `CHAR_BIT` is at least 8.

So, one *byte* in C is not necessarily an *octet*, i.e. 8 bits. In the past one of the first platforms to run C code (and Unix) had 4-byte `int` - but in total `int` had 36 bits, because `CHAR_BIT` was 9!

`int` is supposed to be the natural integer size for the platform that has range of *at least `-32767 ... 32767`*. You can get the size of `int` in the platform bytes with `sizeof(int)`; when you multiply this value by `CHAR_BIT` you will know how wide it is in bits.

---

While 36-bit machines are mostly dead, there are still platforms with non-8-bit bytes. Just yesterday there was [a question about a Texas Instruments MCU with 16-bit bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53204008/918959), that has a C99, C11-compliant compiler.

On [TMS320C28x](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/spru514q/spru514q.pdf) it seems that `char`, `short` and `int` are *all* 16 bits wide, and hence one byte. `long int` is 2 bytes and `long long int` is 4 bytes. The beauty of C is that one can still write an efficient program for a platform like this, and even do it in a portable manner!

Comment: "because CHAR_BIT was 9!" - They had 362880 bit computing back then!? Impressive.

Answer (score 8):

The only guarantees are that `char` must be *at least* 8 bits wide, `short` and `int` must be *at least* 16 bits wide, and `long` must be *at least* 32 bits wide, and that `sizeof (char)` <= `sizeof (short)` <= `sizeof (int)` <= `sizeof (long)` (same is true for the unsigned versions of those types).

`int` may be anywhere from 16 to 64 bits wide depending on the platform.

Answer (score 5):

Mostly it depends on the platform you are using .It depends from compiler to compiler.Nowadays in most of compilers *int* is of *4 bytes*.
If you want to check what your compiler is using you can use `sizeof(int)`.

```
main()
{
    printf("%d",sizeof(int));
    printf("%d",sizeof(short));
    printf("%d",sizeof(long));
}
```

The only thing c compiler promise is that size of short must be equal or less than int and size of long must be equal or more than int.So if size of int is 4 ,then size of short may be 2 or 4 but not larger than that.Same is true for long and int. It also says that size of short and long can not be same.

Comment: Using `%d` for a `size_t` parameter is UB.

Answer (score 3):

This depends on implementation, but usually on x86 and other popular architectures like ARM `int`s take 4 bytes. You can always check at compile time using `sizeof(int)` or whatever other type you want to check.

If you want to make sure you use a type of a specific size, use the types in `<stdint.h>`

Answer (score 3):

> Is the size of C “int” 2 bytes or 4 bytes?
>
> Does an Integer variable in C occupy 2 bytes or 4 bytes?

C allows "bytes" to be something other than 8 bits per "byte".

> > `CHAR_BIT` number of bits for smallest object that is not a bit-field (byte) C11dr §5.2.4.2.1 1

A value of something than 8 is increasingly uncommon.  For maximum portability, use `CHAR_BIT` rather than 8.  The size of an `int` in *bits*  in C is `sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT`.

```
#include <limits.h>
printf("(int) Bit size %zu\n", sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT);
```

---

> What are the factors that it depends on?

The `int` bit size is commonly 32 or 16 bits.  C specified minimum *ranges*:

> > minimum value for an object of type `int` `INT_MIN` -32767
> > maximum value for an object of type `int` `INT_MAX` +32767
> > C11dr §5.2.4.2.1 1

The *minimum range* for `int` forces the bit size to be *at least* 16 - even if the processor was "8-bit".  A size like 64 bits is seen in specialized processors. Other values like 18, 24, 36, etc. have occurred on historic platforms or are at least theoretically possible.  Modern coding rarely worries about non-power-of-2 `int` bit sizes.

The computer's processor and architecture drive the `int` bit size selection.

Yet even with 64-bit processors, the compiler's `int` size may be 32-bit for compatibility reasons as large code bases depend on `int` being 32-bit (or 32/16).

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("size of int: %d", (int)sizeof(int));
    return 0;
}
```

This returns 4, but it's probably machine dependant.

Answer (score -1):

[This is a good source for answering this question.](http://www.rapidtables.com/prog/cref/data_types.htm)

But this question is a kind of a always truth answere "Yes. Both."

It depends on your architecture. If you're going to work on a 16-bit machine or less, it can't be 4 byte (=32 bit). If you're working on a 32-bit or better machine, its length is 32-bit.

To figure out, get you program ready to output something readable and use the "sizeof" function. That returns the size in bytes of your declared datatype. But be carfull using this with arrays.

If you're declaring `int t[12];` it will return 12*4 byte. To get the length of this array, just use `sizeof(t)/sizeof(t[0])`. 
If you are going to build up a function, that should calculate the size of a send array, remember that if

```
typedef int array[12];
int function(array t){
    int size_of_t = sizeof(t)/sizeof(t[0]);
    return size_of_t;
}
void main(){
    array t = {1,1,1};  //remember: t= [1,1,1,0,...,0]
    int a = function(t);    //remember: sending t is just a pointer and equal to int* t
   print(a);   // output will be 1, since t will be interpreted as an int itselve. 
}
```

So this won't even return something different. If you define an array and try to get the length afterwards, use sizeof. If you send an array to a function, remember the send value is just a pointer on the first element. But in case one, you always knows, what size your array has. Case two can be figured out by defining two functions and miss some performance. Define function(array t) and define function2(array t, int size_of_t). Call "function(t)" measure the length by some copy-work and send the result to function2, where you can do whatever you want on variable array-sizes.

Comment: The link provided is a bad source of information because it assumes things that are not always true (e.g. `char` is always `signed`)