# Sending ints and chars through sockets

Tags: c, sockets

I'm writing code for an application using sockets where I have to send integers and strings over the network, but I'm having trouble packing the data into a buffer for transmission. I tried doing this:

```
sendline[0] = htons(3);
sendline[1] = htons(strlen(argv[3]));
for(int i = 0; i < strlen(argv[3]); i++)
{
    sendline[i + 2] = argv[3][i];
}
sendline[2 + strlen(argv[3])] = htons(atoi(argv[4]));
sendline[3 + strlen(argv[3])] = '\0';
```

but it doesn't work.
Where am I going wrong here? Also, what would be the best way to serialize this kind of data?

This is my deserialization code :

```
case '3': // switching on the value of buf[0]
{
    int i;
    int len = ntohs(buf[1]);
    char* ch = (char*)malloc(len * sizeof(char));
    for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        ch[i] = buf[i + 2];
    }
}
```

Comment: What does it mean "It doesn't work"?

Comment: Why did you edited your question? Has it solved the problem?

Comment: When I try to deserialize the buffer at the receiver, I cannot extract the contents. I think my serialization is flawed, but I can't figure out  where the flaw is.

Comment: 1) So the typo has been only here on SO and not in your code? 2)Show us also deserialization part please.

Comment: What is the type of `sendline`?

Comment: http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/161926-mixed-type-contiguous-memory-buffer.html

Comment: what problem you get? Also post more source describing where you receive data and also your buffer `sendline` is what type.

Answer (score 0):

You should user `htonl()`and `ntohl()`, if you are serializing 32 bit (4 byte) integers.

send:

```
int my_integer = INT32_MAX;
uint32_t data = htonl(my_integer);
write(s, &data, sizeof(data));
```

recv:

```
uint32_t data;
read(s, &data, sizeof(data));
int my_integer = ntohl(data);
```

There are many questions on SO already describing serialization and the `htonl()`/`ntohl()` functions, but beware of those omitting endianess. Remember to check return values of `read()` and `write()`.

As for the "strings", do not serialize them, if they are `char` data describing ASCII text. UTF8 also works without serialization, but beware of UTF-16. The important thing to grasp about endianess early on is that it refers to *byte order* and not the order of bits within a byte. IIRC C guarantees that the presentation form of a single byte, so it appears the same on all C platforms.

Answer (score -1):

Buffer sent/received via sockets consists of char, which is [1 byte long](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc953fe1.aspx). Integer/uint16_t type is [longer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11438794/is-the-size-of-c-int-2-bytes-or-4-bytes).

So what you really do, when you try to assign?

```
sendline[0] = htons(3);
```

`sendline[0]` is 1 byte long, but `htons(3)` is 2 bytes long, so you truncate it. Similarly you use `sendline[1]` by:

```
sendline[1] = htons(strlen(argv[3]));
```

Obviously your buffer gets corrupted.

Send integer numbers in one socket and strings in other, convert integers to strings or do not overwrite your buffer (so you have to use `sizeof(int)` on some places)

Comment: Yes that was a typo, sorry. Edited

Comment: You cannot possibly 'overwrite `sendline[1]` by assigning anything to `sendline[0].` What he does need is (a) a cast and (b) some code to handle all the bytes of the integer returned by `htons().` At the moment he is simply *truncating* the value. -1

Comment: @EJP I have tried to explain why the current approach is not working properly, but obviously I hit a limit of my C knowledge:). Feel free to edit my answer and remove any misleading facts. Thanks

Comment: If I convert my integers to strings during serialization, how will I deserialize them unless I know the length of each string?