# Why does printf convert large numbers?

Tags: c, printf, atoi

Why doesn't this work?

```
printf("%d \n\n\n\n", atoi("11110010100"));
```

it outputs -1774891788... I just want it outputted as it is. It seems to work just fine if the number is a bit smaller.

Comment: Why do you assume the problem is with `printf` and not with `atoi`?

Comment: `11110010100` in base 10 converts to base 2 as `1010010110001101010100110011110100` (34 bits)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`atoi` returns an `int`. You pass a string which contains a number bigger than what `int`(in your implementation) can hold. So, you have an integer overflow.

To print the maximum value an `int` can hold, include `limits.h` and print `INT_MAX`.

Comment: could you elaborate on how you would use INT_MAX?

Comment: `printf("%i",INT_MAX);` when you've included `limits.h`

Answer (score 1):

int atoi (const char * str) convert string to integer,and the basic signed integer type capable of containing at least the [−32767,+32767] range,

the 11110010100 is bigger than integer storage capability, so you have an overflow.

you can try this method to parse a String to a Double: **atof**
http://www.lemoda.net/c/string-to-double/

Comment: It would be exceptional to find a system using a two byte integer type these days.

Comment: No, kamel is right: according to K&R, **2.2 Data Types and Size**, "ints are *at least* 16 bits" (see also http://stackoverflow.com/a/11438985/2564301). And `atoi` returns an `int`.