# C System Calls and messages

Tags: c, pointers, int

I am trying to pass a pointer to a system call by passing a message with that call.

The pointer should be to an int[].

However the message definition expects a char pointer to be passed. How can I send an int pointer?

```
int pidarray[j];
m.m1_p1 = pidarray;
```

Is it possible to convert the pointer types?

Comment: Are you thinking of [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) or of the [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) library function when mentioning "C System Calls"? Please edit your question to improve it. Perhaps tag it more precisely (with Linux, POSIX, ...)

Answer (score 1):

`Is it possible to convert the pointer types?`

Yes this is possible. e.g.:

```
(char*) intPointer
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `(char*)`? And wouldn't such a cast return the single bytes from each `int` instead of casting each `int` to a `char`?

Comment: Thanks! How would that work in terms of passing it in the message? Do I convert it to a char*? Then I could pass it back as an int*?

Comment: @cad I gave an example. And yes, the data would be directly converted to chars instead of per int.

Comment: Alright but casting something called `intPointer` to, well, an `int` pointer seems peculiar nevertheless.

Comment: @calmcalmuncle Keep in mind that chars are 1 byte and integers are 4 bytes.

Comment: Thankyou for your answers!

Comment: [Don't say that!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11438794/is-the-size-of-c-int-2-bytes-or-4-bytes)