# Why can I operate with int > +32767?

Tags: c++, int, range, undefined-behavior

I can read that int range (signed) is from [−32767, +32767]
but I can say, for example

```
int a=70000;
int b=71000;
int c=a+b;

printf("%i", c);
return 0;
```

And the output is 141000 (correct). Should not the debugger tell me 
"this operation is out of range" or something similar?

I suppose that this has to be with me ignoring the basics of C programming, but none of the books that I'm currently reading tell nothing about this "issue".

EDIT:
2147483647 seems to be the upper limit, thank you. If a sum exceeds that number, the result is negative, wich is expected, BUT if it is a subtraction, for example: **2147483649-2147483647=2** the result is still good. I mean, why the value 2147483649 is correctly hold for that substraction purpose (or at least it seems to me)?

Comment: If you print `sizeof(int)`, that's the number of **bytes** your `int` can store. That's a hint.

Comment: Are you sure that is the range of int's on your machine? Try printing the number of bytes an int has with sizeof(int).

Comment: On today's machine, is it default to be 32-bit at least for `int`?

Comment: Your `int` is probably 4 bytes, enough to store that value.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11438794/is-the-size-of-c-int-2-bytes-or-4-bytes

Comment: @gongzhitaao The C++ Standard says at least 16 bits to store an `int`.

Comment: The range of int is usually -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647.

Comment: There is not absoute rule on how big an int is in C, depends on the machine, probably yours run with 32 bits int

Comment: That range is usually for _`short`_ `int`.

Comment: @erip "However, on 32/64 bit systems it is almost exclusively guaranteed to have width of at least 32 bits... - [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types)"

Comment: @ikeki - **2147483649-2147483647=2** is really another question, but using values that are too large for an `int` is again undefined behavior. In that case absolutely **anything** can happen, including sometimes getting the correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have misunderstood.  The standard *guarantees* that a `int` holds [-32767, +32767], but it is *permitted* to hold more.  (In particular, nearly every compiler you are likely to use allows a range [-2147483648, 2147483647]).

There is another problem.  If you make the value you assign to a and b bigger *you still probably won't get any warning or error*.  Integer overflow causes "undefined behaviour", and literally anything is allowed to happen.

Comment: "If a sum exceed that number" ... anything can happen.  See this bug report where GCC converted a loop from 0 to 64 to an infinite loop which overwrote all of memory because there was signed integer overflow within the loop.  https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=33498

Comment: 2147483647seems to be the upper limit, thank you. If a sum exceed that number, the result is negative, wich is expected, BUT if it is a subtraction,  for example:  2147483649-2147483647=2 the result is still good. I mean, why the value 2147483649 is correctly hold for that substraction purpose (or at least it seems to me)?

Comment: You are getting (un)lucky.   2147483649 overflows, and results in an `int` with value  -2147483647.  Subtracting  2147483647 from that *should* result in -4294967294, but *that* underflows and you end up with +2.  *HOWEVER* beware that arithmetic overflow is undefined behaviour, and the compiler may assume it doesn't happen - and all sorts of thing go wrong when it does.

Answer (score 6):

The range [−32767, +32767] is the required **minimum** range. An implementation is allowed to provide a larger range.

Comment: I think it's `[-32768, 32767]`.

Comment: @erip - No, that's a common range for 16-bit two's complement systems. But the absolute minimum is slightly smaller to also allow sign-magnitude and one's complement.

Comment: Ah, interesting! TIL. Thanks for keeping me honest. +1

Comment: @erip *I think it's `[-32768, 32767]`* No.  See **[5.2.4.2.1 Sizes of integer types `<limits.h>`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)**

Answer (score 5):

All types are compiler-dependent. `int` used to be the "native word" of the underlying hardware, which on 16-bit systems meant that `int` was 16 bits (which leads to the -32k to +32k range). When 32-bit systems started coming then `int` naturally followed along and became 32 bits, which can store values around -2 billion to +2 billion.

However this "native word" use for `int` didn't follow along when 64-bit systems came around, I know of no 64-bit system or compiler that have `int` being 64 bits.

See e.g. [this reference of integer types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types#Integer_types) for more information.

Answer (score 4):

In C++, `int` is *at least* 16-bits long, but typically 32-bits on modern hardware. You can write `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX` and check yourself.

Note that signed integer overflow is **undefined behavior**, you are not guaranteed to get a warning, except perhaps with high compiler warnings and debug mode.

Comment: There are implementations where INT_MAX is 2147483648, but sizeof(int) is 1. (On such machines, CHAR_BIT will be 32.)

Comment: @MartinBonner ok, yes, strictly speaking one should divide by `CHAR_BIT`. Changed the answer to look at `INT_MAX`.

Answer (score 1):

If an int is four bytes an unsigned is 4294967295, signed max. 2147483647 and signed min. -2147483648

```
unsigned int ui = ~0;
int max = ui>>1;
int min = ~max;
int size = sizeof(max);
```

Answer (score 0):

While the standard guarantees the size of `int` to be 16 bit, it is usually implemented as a 32-bit value.

Answer (score 0):

The size of an `int` (and the max value it can hold) depends on the compiler and the computer you are using. There is no guarantee that it will have 2 bytes or 4 bytes, but there is a *guaranteed minimum size* for the c++ variables.

You can see a list of minimum sizes for c++ types in this page: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/variables/