# Is it safe to use head segment of dynamic array in a multi threaded program?

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic-arrays

When we defined dynamic array in C/C++ it's using head segment to keep track of number of elements in the array(in heap).
for example :

```
int* mem = new int[8];
```

compiler will allocate sizeof(int)*8 bytes.

```
int *temp = malloc(sizeof(int)*9)
```

Will store "8" in the first sizeof(int) bytes and it goes like this

```
*temp = 8;
```

and then set ***mem*** address with next consecutive address respect to ***temp***

```
mem = temp + 1;
```

Therefore,***mem*** will points to an array of 8 elements, not 9.

And when deletion happens compiler will  use ***mem***  in reverse process respect to above to deallocate memory in that heap block

```
delete[] mem;
```

***My question is***
If we allocate a dynamic memory which will be used in different modules in run-time and we managed to retrieve number of elements using **head segment** of allocated heap memory,Is it safe to use in Multi-threaded environment?

(Please assume that in each module by program design,no helper function or attribute provided to retrieve number of elements(**size**) in defined dynamic array.Each module only passing address(pointers) to array but not its size)

Comment: You're assuming a lot of implementation details here. I don't really understand the question, anyway. What is your goal? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Whatever you put in a malloc'd area is safe until it gets deallocated. Beware anyway that an int occupies 4 bytes.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? What is the reasoning behind it? What is the real problem that you want to solve?

Comment: @YvesDaoust: It may not.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, who told you that `int` occupies 4 bytes?

Comment: @YvesDaoust, well, my recent `int`s are occupying 2 bytes. What your 30 years of coding have to say to it?

Comment: @YvesDaoust: [You'll need a few more years then!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11438840/560648) Don't forget to read as well as code.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: Then you already know that what you are claiming is not true.

Comment: Your question is still unclear. Accessing arrays in a multithreaded environment is safe in the sense that it will not crash, but you may end up reading partially updated (i.e. corrupted) data if some other thread updated the array.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: int has been 32 bits for the last 20 years and will remain so in the future.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, I can only repeat myself - as recently as yesterday I was working with modern hardware with 16 bit int.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: `int` is still 16 bits on most architectures and can have 1-2 bytes easily! You might have to extend your horizon; 32 or 64 systems are still the minority.

Comment: @olaf: back in 1992, the 64 bits DEC Alpha was a dream processor ! I also enjoyed (years before) the IBM 360 storing FORTRAN BOOLEANS in 72 bits words.

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not safe in any environment. You can't rely on the compiler storing the number of elements in the array before the allocated memory, as it is not defined behavior. You should never try to get to this value.

Instead, do not even use dynamic arrays, but opt for `std::vector`.

Comment: To be fair, Buddhika did say "**if** we managed to retrieve number of elements"

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, yes indeed. I will try to make the point clearer.

Comment: I don't think that the OP uses addresses "before". He uses the first byte to store the size.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, I believe, OP is trying to get to the value used by compiler internally.

Comment: @SergeyA: you didn't look at the code. `*temp= 8` clearly stores the length in the first position.

Comment: ,Thank for the reply all of you such quick time!!

Comment: regardless it's still UB because of `realloc` (which may use the same location). Unless the OP can guarantee that the pointer will not be modified in either module it creates a potential data race. That still ignores the fact that it's UB from a standards perspective as the standard doesn't require such an implementation and the implementation is free do do other things to track allocations.

Comment: @Mgetz: no, realloc won't cause any trouble (provided care is taken to restore the initial value of the pointer, like will be done before a free).

Comment: @YvesDaoust, I believel, OP is illustrating the point by arguing about compiler behavior.

Comment: @YvesDaoust it will in a multi-threaded environment if the size of the array is modified but the location is not. It breaks the rules requiring a data-race free program.

Comment: @SergeyA,instead of std::vector,most of game engine dev' companies use some magic tricks to keep track of number of elements rather than rely on std::containers,some of them use sometimes functions like _alloca and _malloca within a function boundaries to alloc mem on stack based on some allocated mem ,for that they need size to define i.
Please refer -> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5471dc8s.aspx

Comment: @Buddhika, I see no reason to use `alloca` when in C++ VLAs are supported as extension in any sensible compiler. On any rate, no-allocation approach is very different from your original question.

Comment: @SergeyA I just go through this article 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard
Yeah I will try another approach,but if you find any theoretical or compiler dependent or independent logic please reply.

Comment: Quite a few games used to allocate a massive block of memory and then use their own memory manager to hand it out as required. This should give you as much control as you need without infringing on the runtime or the OS.

Comment: @Mgetz: the system will take care that the block header remains consistent with the block and the heap state. So, no, no trouble (of course reading the size and accessing the block must be made atomically).

Comment: And while I'm not a fan of VLA, VLA seems much safer to me than having stack-based storage you can forget to return.

Comment: @Buddhika just use the [GSL](https://github.com/Microsoft/gsl) it has range constructs, and they are very lightweight.

Comment: @Mgetz thank you very much for the tip!! it's really helpful!!

Answer (score 1):

Accessing `mem - 1` has undefined behaviour.

> compiler will ...

If you target that version of compiler, and that version only, and the compiler vendor documents the behaviour, then perhaps you can trust that the version of the compiler indeed does as you have observed.

But a program that depends on it will be non-portable to other compilers, and possibly other versions of that same compiler, and possibly to other platforms that use same version of the same compiler.

This is all regardless of multi vs single thread.

---

> If we allocate a dynamic memory which will be used in different modules in run-time and we managed to retrieve number of elements using head segment of allocated heap memory,Is it safe to use in Multi-threaded environment?

It is safe to use dynamic memory in a multi threaded program as much as it is safe to use any memory. Of course, multi threaded implies the potential for data races. You must synchronize modifications to any objects that may simultaneously be accessed by other threads. Whether the objects are in dynamic memory makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

I tested this with Visual Studio release build:

```
int * mem = new int[8];
```

results in a call to malloc equivalent to

```
int * mem = malloc(32);    // 32 = 8 * sizeof(int)
```

The size of the integer array is not stored anywhere, (including the malloc header as far as I can tell, the malloc header just has some type of link/flag used to recombine blocks allocated (and virtually mapped) from the heap).

Answer (score 0):

Using undocumented system information is in principle out of question, even if it seems to work: it might behave differently in unexpected circumstances and there is no guarantee of portability, even across the same manufacturer over time.

If you want to play with matches anyway, make sure that no other thread performs a memory-allocation-related operation between the moment you read the size and the moment you access the block; you need to implement a critical section for this purpose.

Comment: An extra warning: You can protect your code with whatever you like, but you won't have much luck blocking the runtime from tinkering if it feels the need.

Comment: @user4581301: yep. I guess that the only guarantee that the system can provide is that the content of the block pointed to by the malloc pointer doesn't change  between <memory> calls, which are thread-safe.