# Read binary file to integer range of -32767 to 32767

Tags: c, binary, short

I need to make a program to read a binary file into the range of -32767 to 32767. So far, the script below read the binary file into the range of -128 to 127.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  FILE *fp = NULL;
  signed char shint[2000] = "";
  int i = 0;
  size_t  bytes = 0;

  if ((fp = fopen("raw_data.ht3", "rb")) == NULL) {
    printf ("could not open file\n");
    return 0;
  }
  if ((bytes = fread(&shint, 1, 2000, fp)) > 0 ) {  //bytes more than 0
    for (i = 0; i < bytes; i++) {
      printf ("%d\n", shint[i]);
    }
  }
  fclose(fp);
  return 0;
}
```

More info about the binary file, my lecturer said the binary file should be read into 4 bytes data (I'm not sure my wording is right here). The data is very big so I stop the data reading till 2000 data. Though in the future I need to read all of them.

[The final data representation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFMFQ.png)

This is how I want to plot at the end of the day. I will call our matlab or scilab after getting the desired data.

Thanks!

Comment: You probably want to read either 2 or 4 bytes at a time.  (Your question title suggests two bytes, your lecturer said four).  You can probably use `fread`. (Byte swapping is theoretically an issue, but for this exercise you can probably ignore it.)

Comment: How do I read 2 or 4 bytes at a time?

Comment: Your question says that you want a short[] array.  Your teacher said you want an int[] array.

Comment: @HansPassant I think I need to stick with 4 bytes per reading.

Comment: To avoid differences in type size between compilers, if the specification is that the integers in the file are 4 bytes each, it would be safest to include `<stdint.h>` and use either `int32_t` or `unint32_t`, depending on whether the integers are supposed to be interpreted as signed or unsigned.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts which invalidate the comments and answers posted below. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted. If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323395)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i understand you want easy access to chars and signed 16 bits ints.

```
#define SIZE 2000

union
{
    char shint_c[SIZE * 2];
    short shint[SIZE];
}su;
```

and then in your if

```
fread(&su, 2, SIZE, fp)
```

and in the loop to print shorts

```
printf ("%hd\n", su.shint[i]);
```

or 8 bits ints

```
printf ("%hhd\n", su.shint_c[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `4` bytes representation for your input data, i. e. replace

```
signed char shint[2000] = "";
```

with

```
long int shint[2000] = "";
```

and

```
 if ((bytes = fread(&shint, 1, 2000, fp)) > 0 ) {  //bytes more than 0
```

with

```
 if ((bytes = fread(&shint, 4, 2000, fp)) > 0 ) {  //bytes more than 0
```

and

```
printf ("%d\n", shint[i]);
```

with

```
printf ("%ld\n", shint[i]);
```

---

Note:

By the name of your variable (`shint`, i. e. `short int`) and by the range `-32768` to `+32767` it seems that your instructor wanted `2` bytes for numbers, not `4`.
In that case use `short int` (or simply `short`) in your declaration and `2` as the second parameter of `fread()` function.

Comment: `long int` isn't guaranteed to be 4 bytes.

Comment: he needs 2 bytes not 4

Answer (score 0):

I don't have your data to test on (and I didn't tested out my answer) but it should be something like this:

First of all `signed char shint[2000] = "";` is holding 2000 signed chars (which are indeed signed 8 bit values have a look [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_data_types.htm) - this is a very handy resource when handling data types sizes) , so you need some value to hold signed 32 bit (4 byte) values, which depends on your machine architecture, assuming it is 32 bit integer ([it is not difficult to find out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11438794/is-the-size-of-c-int-2-bytes-or-4-bytes)) you could hold you values in `int shint[2000] = "";`

next thing you need to pay attention to is the function `fread` [here is some friendly documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread/), the second parameter to this function (which is 1 in your code) should be the number of bytes represents a single value from the data you want to read from, so in your situation should be 4 (bytes). the other parameters should be OK.

edit: to make sure you are reading 4 bytes you can use indeed the answer given by MarianD and store `long` values.