# How does uint32_t guarantee 32 bits?

Tags: c++, c, int, size, int32

In most implementations, I've seen `uint32_t` defined as

```
typedef unsigned int uint32_t;
```

But as I understand it `ints` are [not always guaranteed to be 4 bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11438794/is-the-size-of-c-int-2-bytes-or-4-bytes) across all systems. So if the system has non 4-byte integers, how does `uint32_t` guarantee 4?

Comment: Presumably it's only defined that way on systems where `int` is 4 bytes. Have you looked at how it's defined on other systems?

Comment: The file where you found that specific definition comes with the specific system you looked it up on. On systems with different type sizes, that file will hold a different definition.

Comment: it's in the name

Comment: This is pure C and has nothing to do with C++, so it should have been tagged C. Too late to fix it now, as some answers address C++. Please see [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/360824/584518) (community wiki under construction, anyone is welcome to contribute).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An implementation is required to define `uint32_t` correctly (or not at all if that's not possible).

If `unsigned int` meets the requirements (32 bits wide, no padding bits), the implementation can define it as

```
typedef unsigned int uint32_t;
```

If it doesn't, but `unsigned long` does meet the requirements, it can define it as:

```
typedef unsigned long uint32_t;
```

Or it can use a different unsigned type if that's appropriate.

The `<stdint.h>` header has to be compatible with the compiler that it's used with. If you took a `<stdint.h>` header that unconditionally defined `uint32_t` as `unsigned int`, and used it with a compiler that makes `unsigned int` 16 bits, the result would be a non-conforming implementation.

Compatibility can be maintained either by tailoring the header to the compiler, or by writing the header so that it adapts to the characteristics of the compiler.

As a programmer, you don't have to worry about *how* correctness is maintained (though of course there's nothing wrong with being curious). You can rely on it being done correctly -- or you can complain to the provider about a serious bug.

Comment: "Or it can use a different unsigned type if that's appropriate." ... or can be compiler intern representation or whatever

Comment: Or   built in type

Answer (score 2):

Each C or C++ implementation that defines `uint32_t` defines it in a way that works for that implementation. It may use `typedef unsigned int uint32_t;` only if `unsigned int` is satisfactory for `uint32_t` in that implementation.

The fact that `typedef unsigned int uint32_t;` appears in `<stdint.h>` in one C or C++ implementation  does not mean it will appear in `<stdint.h>` for any other C or C++ implementation. An implementation in which `unsigned int` were not suitable for `uint32_t` would have to provide a different `<stdint.h>`. `<stdint.h>` is part of the implementation and changes when the implementation changes.

Answer (score 1):

> `uint32_t` guarantee 32 bits?

Yes.

---

If `CHAR_BIT == 16`, `uint32_t` would be 2 "bytes".  A "byte" is not always 8 bits in C.

The size of `int` is not a major issue concerning the implementation `uintN_t`.

`uintN_t` (N = 8,16,32,64) are optional non-padded types that independently exist when and if the system can support them.  It is extremely common to find them implemented, especially the larger ones.

`intN_t` is similarly optional and must be 2's complement.

Comment: The question asks how, not whether.