# Different results for factorial calculation in C, Python and JavaScript

Tags: c, factorial

I wrote some simple code in Python, JavaScript and C.  I found that the Python and JavaScript results are the same, but C gives me another -wrong- result and I can't understand what is the error.

C code:

```
int fact(int n){
    if(n==1){
        return 1;
    }else{
        return (n*fact(n-1));
    }
}

int main(void){
    printf("%i \n",fact(13));
}
```

JS code:

```js
function fact(n){
    if (n==1){
        return (1);
    }else{
        return (n*fact(n-1));
    }
}

console.log(fact(13));
```

Python code:

```
def fact(n):
    if(n == 0):
        return 1
    else:
        return n * fact(n - 1)

print(fact(13))
```

Can you explain?

Comment: Never done any C, but I bet that the desired result of 6227020800 is just too big [to fit in an int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11438794/is-the-size-of-c-int-2-bytes-or-4-bytes)

Comment: thank you for your speedy reply but what can i use for too big intgers?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types makes me think maybe `unsigned long long int`

Comment: Use `long long` [64 bit wide] instead of `int` [32 bit wide]. Also, (e.g.) `printf("%lld\n",num);` instead of `printf("%d\n",num);`

Comment: `unsigned long long` would be the best option, but bear in mind it's limited as well and it won't be able to hold values past ~`fact(20)`.

Comment: Also note that your python version works for n as low as 0, but your C and javascript versions only work down to 1 because they're checking `n == 1` instead of `n == 0`.  `n == 0` is preferred, since it alllows your function to work for all non-negative integers (until it overflows).  (`0!` is well-defined and its value is `1`)

Comment: @CristiFati then fact(21) give wrong result, what should we use to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being interpreted languages, they (probably) automatically choose the data type for variables according to the size of the data.

However, in C you specified that `"int"` has to be used - and it is way too small to hold 13!

If you switch `"int"` for `"unsigned long long int"` (yes, use "long" twice), then your program will return proper results for a longer time, until it fails again - exceeding the size of 64-bits.