# why cant I convert a string into an int in c

Tags: c, type-conversion, atoi

Assume that we have a char array `input = "12345678987654321"`, why cant I use `atoi()` to convert it into integer `12345678987654321`? I have tried this and it returned some numbers that I couldn't understand.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char num[20];
    scanf("%s\n", num);
    printf("%d", atoi(num));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is `sizeof int` in your system? What is `INT_MAX`?

Comment: Because `atoi` returns an `int` is limited in size and range? Normally to 32 bits which means it will have a range from about minus two billion to plus two billion.

Comment: @Gerhardh INT_MAX = 30

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude so we need to convert it into double?

Comment: Also note that [`atoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/atoi) have *no* error checking of any kind. If you want to have error checking and validation use [`strtol`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol).

Comment: Also the error checking should begin at the input with `scanf("%19s",num);` (and remove the newline).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude but then can we use atof?

Comment: `float` will not be able to handle numbers that high in a good way (if at all), I'm not sure about `double`. If you want a large integer, use `long long` which, if supported, will have at least 64 bits.

Comment: @welp..., `INT_MAX` definitely is not 30.  This is a parameter of the machine's integer representation, exposed automatically to your code in the form of a preprocessor macro.  In a conforming C implementation, it will not be less than 32767.  In most implementations these days it is in excess of 2 billion.  If somehow it really were 30 then your C implementation would be deeply crippled.

Comment: The first chapters of any beginner-level C programming book typically address numerical limits of integer types. Start by reading those. See if you can find the magic number 2.14 * 10^9 somewhere, or perhaps the equivalent 2^31 - 1.

Comment: strongly suggest using `strtoll()` to do the conversion.  Remember to read/understand the MAN page for that function.

Answer (score 2):

“12345678987654321” is generally too large for an `int`, and `atoi` does not provide error detection.

You can use the `strto…` functions to convert a numeral in a string to an integer type. Below is an example using `strtoimax`, for the widest signed integer type a C implementation supports. There are also versions for other types, such as `strtoll` for `long long`.

The `strto…` functions provide error checking, so you can detect when a number is too large and report it to the user or otherwise handle it.

```
#include <ctype.h>      // For isdigit and isspace.
#include <errno.h>      // For errno.
#include <inttypes.h>   // For stroimax and PRIdMAX.
#include <stdint.h>     // For intmax_t.
#include <stdio.h>      // For printf, fprintf, getchar, and ungetc.
#include <stdlib.h>     // For exit.


int main(void)
{
    // Read string.
    char string[20];
    int n = 0; // Number of characters read so far.
    while (1)
    {
        int c = getchar();

        // When we see the end of the input stream, leave the loop.
        if (c == EOF)
            break;

        /* When we see a white-space character (including new-line), put it
           back into the stream and leave the loop.
        */
        if (isspace(c))
        {
            ungetc(c, stdin);
            break;
        }

        /* If we see character that is not a space or a digit, complain, unless
           it is the first character and is a sign, "+" or "-".
        */
        if (!isdigit(c) && !(n == 0 && (c == '+' || c == '-')))
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error, non-digit seen:  \"%c\".\n", c);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        // Record the digit.
        string[n++] = c;

        if (sizeof string / sizeof *string <= n)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error, too many digits, can handle only %zu.\n",
                sizeof string / sizeof *string - 1);
                /* ("sizeof *string" is one for ordinary "char" arrays, but
                   using it allows changing to wide character types if
                   desired.)
                */
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    };
    // Finish string with a null character.
    string[n] = '\0';

    // Attempt to convert string to an intmax_t.
    char *end;
    errno = 0; // Initialize error indicator.
    intmax_t number = strtoimax(string, &end, 0);

    /* Test whether the string failed to match the form for a numeral, because
       it was empty or was just a sign with no digits.
    */
    if (end == string)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error, numeral has no digits.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Check for error.
    if (errno != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error, number is too large for intmax_t.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Test whether the whole string was used in the conversion. It should have
       been, considering we ensured each character was a digit, but a check
       like this can be useful in other situations, where we are parsing a
       numeral from a more general string.
    */
    if (*end != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error, unexpected character in numeral, \"%c\".\n",
            *end);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Print the number.
    printf("The number is %" PRIdMAX ".\n", number);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason you get weird output is the number entered is beyond the range of values representable with the `int` type. The `atoi()` function does not necessarily perform error checking, it actually has undefined behavior if the number cannot be represented as an `int`. You should use `strtol()` instead.

Your program has another potential undefined behavior: `scanf("%s\n", num)` may write beyond the end of the `num` array with dire consequences if the user inputs more than 19 characters. You should write `scanf("%19s", num)` and test the return value for potential conversion errors.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char num[20];

    if (scanf("%19s", num) != 1) {
        printf("no input\n");
        return 1;
    }
    int c = getchar();
    if (c != '\n' && c != EOF) {
        printf("too many characters\n");
        ungetc(c, stdin);
    }
    char *end;
    errno = 0;
    long value = strtol(num, &end, 10);
    if (end == num) {
        printf("input is not a number: %s", num);
    } else {
        if (errno != 0) {
            printf("number %s is too large for type long\n", num);
        } else
        if (value < INT_MIN || value > INT_MAX) {
            printf("number %ld is too large for type int\n", value);
        } else {
            printf("value is %d\n", (int)value);
        }
        if (*end != '\0') {
            printf("extra characters after the number: %s", end);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are giving input of "12345678987654321" atoi is in int and the range of int is from `-2,147,483,648 - 2,147,483,647` so in order to fix it use `atol()` l-long,its just because of range or if you are using 32bit machine then you need to use long long int i.e atoll() instead of atol()
[data size](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/references/unix/digital/AQTLTBTE/DOCU_031.HTM)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    char num[20];
    scanf("%s",num);
    //printf("\n%s",num);
    printf("\n%ld",atol(num)); //<- atoi(num) to atol(num)
    return 0;
}
```

[atol()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/atoi) check this for more `atoi()`,`atol()` and `atoll()`

Comment: You are probably right about the range of `int` in the OP's C implementation, but not necessarily.  The C language allows implementations to have both narrower and wider ranges for `int`, and both alternatives can be seen in real implementations.

Comment: @JohnBollinger oh, i understand but not completely can you give me something to read on what you are explaining to me some article or reading material

Comment: `atol()` has the same problem as `atoi()`:  if you pass it `"fish"`, you get a valid integer value out of it.  Neither has any way to report an error because every possible return value is a valid result.

Comment: @MONUTAMBOLI, a little Googling on "size of int" or "range of int" would turn up many appropriate results.  Among them, this: [Is the size of C int 2 bytes or 4 bytes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11438794/is-the-size-of-c-int-2-bytes-or-4-bytes)  For that particular question, be sure to read at least the top three answers.